# fflush fails on Visual C++ 2010 

Tags: c, visual-c++, stream, filehandle, fflush

I'm trying to run some code but `fflush()` with the error:

```
 Invalid file descriptor. File possibly closed by a different thread
```

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
    fhandle = fopen("dbfile.bin", "rbc");
    /* There is a valid dbfile.bin file - get file size */
    _fstat(_fileno(fhandle), &file_stat);
    printf("dbfile.bin size = %d\n", file_stat.st_size);

    g_tpd_list = (tpd_list*)calloc(1, file_stat.st_size);

    if (!g_tpd_list)
    {
        rc = MEMORY_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        fread(g_tpd_list, file_stat.st_size, 1, fhandle);
        fflush(fhandle);
        fclose(fhandle);
    }
```

Comment: Usually you'd flush the file when you're writing to it (to clear the write buffer)...you shouldn't need to flush it for what you're doing, what effect are you expecting?

Comment: i'm not expecting anything. this part of the code is provided by the instructor as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, it seems like this behaviour is caused by the fact that you're passing the `'c'` mode into your `fopen` call.  The help says this about the flag:

> Enable the commit flag for the associated filename so that the contents of the file buffer are written directly to disk if either fflush or _flushall is called

So I'm not sure why it's causing it to behave the way it is.  However, if you remove it, the `fflush` call works.  It could be that this flag is *undoing* the ability for `fflush` to clear the read buffer and making it always attempt to clear the write buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`fflush` is supposed to flush the write buffer. By standard C It is an undefined behavior to call `fflush` on read-only streams. It seems that Microsoft CRT treats such call as an error. You do not need the `fflush` in your case anyway.

UPD:
According to clarifications from comments my suggestion is not completely correct.
Microsoft CRT has a special meaning for `fflush` on read streams. It clears the effect of `ungetc`

Comment: Not actually what the VS help says 'If the stream is open for input, fflush clears the contents of the buffer. fflush negates the effect of any prior call to ungetc against stream'

Comment: @forsvarir, sure, that is a feature I was not aware of. However, there are no calls to ungetc in this code sample